# Making a button create a new label each time its pressed

Tags: c#, wpf, button, label

I'm trying to make this button create a new label every time its clicked, the label's content will be called from a textbox called EventContentInput. I'm stuck on this.

```
 private void btnEvent_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Label eventCreateText = new Label();
        eventCreateText.Content = eventContentInput; //Event Content Input from  Input Form
        eventCreateText.Margin = new Thickness(0, 440, 836, 40);
    }
```

Comment: What is the actual issue which you are having?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You created the control, but you didn't add it to anything. For it to be rendered, it has to be given to its parent control.

In Windows forms, just write:

```
Controls.Add(eventCreateText);
```

This will add it to the form that the code is in. In WPF:

```
SomeContainer.Children.Add(eventCreateText);
```

This will add it to "SomeContainer" which needs to be a `Grid`, `StackPanel` etc.

Comment: Awesome, out of curiosity how would I set label creation position on a grid?

Comment: @user3708761 Depends on how you want to position it. If you want an "absolute" position, just set the "Margin" property. If you want to use the Row/Column system, you need to use the Grid.SetRow method (or Grid.SetColumn)

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot, and one last thing, I get this error when clicking on the button to create the label.

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll

Additional information: Must disconnect specified child from current parent Visual before attaching to new parent Visual.

Comment: @user3708761 You're getting that on the label? Something sounds wrong with that. I'd try googling it or asking a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to do this.Controls.Add(eventCreateText);